# How Can I add a signature field with EO.Pdf.HtmlToPdf?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, digital-signature, html-to-pdf

We sign PDF documents by ELDOS.SecureBlackBox library which can place visible signature everywhere in document, but if we generate PDF dynamically by HtmlToPdf, right place for visible signature is various. This problem can be solved by adding signature field to PDF document and  SecureBlackBox shows signature on this place. But the question is, how can I add a signature field with HtmlToPdf.